# Acer Swift 3 - Crazy fans when turned on while on AC

Tags: fan, tlp, charging

I've got a problem on my Acer Swift 3 (SF314-52G-5848 -- i5-8250U + GF MX150). Ever since installed Ubuntu 16.04 (then 17.04) (now Kubuntu 17.10) dual boot with Win 10, when I turn on the laptop (Ubuntu system) while charging, all fans go crazy and don't stop spinning even when idling or sleeping (without suspend - turned off screen). They just can't be stopped. This doesn't happen when I turn on the laptop and plug in the charger after turned on. I simply can't turn it on while on cable. I've tried TLP, different drivers for dedicated graphics...

Comment: What does a "crazy fan" actually do? Speed up & slow down? Or just stays on high? Is fancontrol installed? When the fans are "crazy" is fancontrol still running (can check with `pgrep -a fancontrol`). Can you see the fan speeds with `sensors`?

Comment: When the system boots, fans speed up (not the highest possible speed, like when gaming, but still pretty fast and loud) and stay at the same speed all the time, idling, doing sth, all the time. Well, actually, I've tried fancontrol and couldn't pass one step (nope, I don't see fan speed with sensors), so fancontrol have never actually worked like it should

Comment: It has to deal somehow with the processor on "performance" mode I think. When it's only on battery, the U-processor has the "turbo mode" turned off. There has to be problem somewhere in the booting process, when the processor reach it's "turbo mode" clock speed while booting, fans turn on and won't stop even when the proc comes back to normal clocks

Comment: Fancontrol needs to be able to see the fan speeds & to control them, running `sensors-detect` might get the required modules identified & say how to load them. The "fancontrol" tag should probably be removed from the Q, since it's not part of the problem now - is TLP or should it be removed too? Maybe bios related if Ubuntu can't see/change the fans, you might be able to see the processor frequency with `cpufreq-info` from the `cpufrequtils` package if it's funny, maybe the governor's keeping the speed up & it is heating up, so needs more fans. Changing to the conservative governor might help?